# select with dynamic id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is dynamically generated, and has dynamically generated id's (and potentially classes). The forms are the same but they have the related id tacked on to the end.

How can I select each set of  and apply code  to each one?

```
switch(id_type_champ)
            {
            case 1:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<input type="text" id='+Id+'  >  ').trigger("create");
              break;
            case 2:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<input type="text" id='+Id+' > ').trigger("create");
              break;
            case 3:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<input type="date" id='+Id+' OnClick="aff_date(\'' + Id + '\')">').trigger("create");
              break;
            case 4:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+'    ><option value=0></option></select>').trigger("create");

                v++;
                 break;
            case 5:
                $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 6:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 7:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 8:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 9:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            default:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
             break;
            }
```

the code can perform the addition of option

Comment: You could use php to select or pass different id's if its not a dynamic no loading thing

Comment: i should  use Javascript. because i develop mobile appl

Answer (score 0):

You can append cases like this:

```
switch (id_type_champ) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        $('#header-right-container').append(nom_champ + '<input type="text" id=' + Id + ' > ').trigger("create");
        break;
    case 3:
        $('#header-right-container').append(nom_champ + '<input type="date" id=' + Id + ' OnClick="aff_date(\'' + Id + '\')">').trigger("create");
        break;
    // The cases below can be removed, except dor "default"
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    // ^ These can be removed.
    default:
        $('#header-right-container').append(nom_champ + '<select id=' + Id + ' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

        v++;
        break;
}
```

Cases 1 through 3 will create a `input`, and 4 through 9 and default a `select`.
You could remove cases 4-9, though, as the default would take care of those.

Also, prefixing a empty string to `nom_champ` (`'' + nom_champ`) is not needed. I assume that was used to cast `nom_champ` to a string, but the `'<input/select'` that's appended will take care of that.

Comment: i have this function `liste_id_Valeur1(id)` will be used for every id of select

Comment: That's still possible, it's just not necessary to specify those different cases from 4-9.

Comment: `default:
        $('#header-right-container').append(nom_champ + '<select id=' + Id + ' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");
liste_id_Valeur1(id)
        v++;
        break;`
 like this?

Comment: i'll try and come back to you

Comment: it's work only for last select, but i have many select in a for loop

`for(k;k<6;k++){ switch(id_type_champ)... }`

Comment: But i should  use the ID of every select, and this IS our dynamic created

Answer (score 0):

It'd be ideal to create your own plugin for this, such as your original function here:

```
function ListIds(var Id) {
switch(id_type_champ)
            {
            case 1:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<input type="text" id='+Id+'  >  ').trigger("create");
              break;
            case 2:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<input type="text" id='+Id+' > ').trigger("create");
              break;
            case 3:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<input type="date" id='+Id+' OnClick="aff_date(\'' + Id + '\')">').trigger("create");
              break;
            case 4:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+'    ><option value=0></option></select>').trigger("create");

                v++;
                 break;
            case 5:
                $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 6:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 7:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 8:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            case 9:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
              break;
            default:
                 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

                v++;
             break;
            }

}
```

Then, the plugin calls this code:

```
    (function($){  
     $.fn.listIdValue = function() {  

        return this.each(function() {  
             ListIds($(this).id)

        });  
     };  
    })(jQuery);
```

Then you can call this function on your elements or a list of elements, such as :

```
$('#element').listIdValue();
```

or

```
$('.elementClass').listIdValue();
```